# Incompatible types for comparison PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am getting these warnings in my powerapp "Incompatible types for comparison. These types can't be compared Number,Text. However, the app seems to work fine but displays a red error warning on the top to end users.

```
If(
    Param("View") = "View",
    true
) Or (varFormMode <> FormMode.New And (Or(
    Param("Owner") = LookUp(
        
        ID = Param("ID")
    ).'Group Owner Email',
    Or(
        Param("DG") = LookUp(
            
            ID = Param("ID")
        ).'DG Approver Email',
        Param("Cloud") = LookUp(
            
            ID = Param("ID")
        ).'Cloud Admin Email'
    )
)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is related to the LookUp() functions. The ID=Param("ID") filter query.

Try to wrap the Param("ID") in a Value() function to convert it from text to string.

```
Param("Owner") = LookUp(
    
    ID = Value(Param("ID"))
).'Group Owner Email',
```